# is app approved by apple which is xc adhoc * dist profile selected while submiting app on appstore?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have selected xc adhoc * distribution profile while submitting app on app store. I think I should have select app specific distribution profile.

but now it waiting for review state. my question is it approved by apple or not?

or I need to resubmit app on iTunes.

Appreciate for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will be rejected. This is strange that the automatic checks did not raise an issue.

App for App Store should be signed using an App Store Mobile Provision and a Distribution Certificate

You can find more information on [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH36-SW2)